# How to zoom and crop image in a single image view using two images

Tags: android

I am doing an application, that has to display an image(pic from sdcard) and another image on top of it(square),that looks like a square where only the middle visible portion of square is to be cropped. The image that is visible inside the square should be able to zoom. I am able to zoom the image separately when the square image is not present. but i want the image to be zoomed in the center visible part when square image is present . And this square image can only be used for panning and must not be zoomed. Someone please help me doing this. This pic shows how it looks like.

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use Border images on the four sides of the Main single image, then create a bitmap of the visible region resolution by neglecting the border images and use  the cropped bitmap wherever you want.I have done this thing by following the above procedure and its working really fine for me.......Thank you.